# Array shows different addresses, before and after being passed to a function by reference

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I was curious to know why the addresses of the same array i.e array b in my case is changing before and after it has been passed to the function manipulation(), as shown in the output picture.
[image]Please share your thoughts and help me figure this out. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
void manipulation(int *pa,int *pb){   
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        *(pb+i)=*(pa+i);
        printf("%d\t  %04x\n",*pb+i,&pb+i);
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[10],b[10];
    int i;

    int *point;
    point = &b[0];
    printf("Enter the array elements\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        scanf("%d\n",&a[i]);    
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%04x\n",&point+i);
    }

    manipulation(&a[0],&b[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't write this `*(pb+i)=*(pa+i);` this way `pb[i]=pa[i];`?

Comment: what are you expecting from `&point+i`?

Comment: BTW `scanf("%d\n",&a[i]);`  --> `scanf("%d",&a[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the real problems is comparing the address of `point` to the address of `pb`.

Try using `point + i` (or `&point[i]`) and `pb + i` (or `&pb[i]`). I'm sure you will get the expected answer.

---

In case you are curious, `&point + i` is the location in memory of the local variable `point` plus the value of `i`. `&pb + i` is the location in memory of the parameter `pb` plus the value of `i`. They are different variables, so they have different locations in memory.

Comment: Thank you so much, so much for pointers I did not realize that I was looking at the address of the pointer rather than the address it is pointing to. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

because you print (*address* of your pointer) + i:

```
printf("%04x\n",&point+i);
printf("%d\t  %04x\n",*pb+i,&pb+i);
```

you want to print the pointer + i:

```
printf("%04x\n",point+i);
printf("%d\t  %04x\n",*pb+i,pb+i);
```

Also you have a bug in there:

```
printf("%d\t  %04x\n",*pb+i,pb+i);
```

`*pb+i` is interpreted as `(*pb) + i` that is the first value of the array plus i, or simply `pb[0]+i`.

you seem to get the right answer because your array is 1 2 3 ...

you probably want this:

```
printf("%d\t  %04x\n",*(pb+i),pb+i);
```

or simply:

```
printf("%d\t  %04x\n",pb[i],pb+i);
```

Answer (score 0):

point stores the address of array a. &point prints the address of point and adding 4 through out the loop. same is the case with &pb. 28fee8 is the place where point is stored and 28fed4 is the place where pb is stored.